# How do I obtain diamonds in Hades?

Tags: hades

The House Contractor says I need 1 diamond to free Orpheus from solitary confinement. I haven't run into any diamonds in any runs I've done, just obols and darkness and nectar and gemstones. I've only beat Megara once, so maybe it's something in Asphodel I haven't reached yet, but I'm not sure.

How do I get diamonds? Is it just that I've not progressed far enough yet, or do I have to unlock something else first (like some of the other house bits or what have you)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get a diamond for defeating the Bone Hydra and escaping Asphodel, the second biome of Hades. This is the primary way to get diamonds

You can also get diamonds from the Fated List of Minor Prophecies and from the Wretched Broker, though I think the broker trade is unlocked by defeating the Bone Hydra anyway.

Comment: It's worth noting that you get 1 diamond per weapon per heat level.

Comment: until you have beaten the game at least once, diamonds are in short supply. The six diamonds for beating the bone hydra are the only ones relatively easy to acquire at that point. I don't think there are prophecies that give diamonds you can realistically do at that point. The regular deal for a diamond with the Wretched Broker is also not affordable, the random deal of the day though might be possible, though also difficult.

Comment: Theres also a permanent Charon shop in the 4th area, and that shop has a 50/50 chance of having a diamon for 1k coins, or titan blood for 1.2k coins.